# image file variable and file itself are not coming to PHP process page when passing variable via jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery

All other input type text and textarea values are properly passed on PHP processed page via jQuery (.js) page except input type file (image). Can anybody please help?

**upload.php**

```
<form name="Uform" id="Uform" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**upload.js**

```
var FileData = $('#img').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', FileData);

$.ajax({
    url: "./user/upload_.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        img: form_data
    },
    cache: false,
 })
```

**upload_p.php**

```
$str_photo = "";
if(isset($_FILES['img'])) { $str_photo = trim($_FILES['img']['name']); }
```

Comment: Does your js upload logic is set in the button submit event ? You have to submit your ajax request before the  the html form validation.

Comment: When button is submitted, all variables go to .js page and then go to PHP process page where image upload function is written along with database query to insert data in database. Image upload and insert data functions are working in working condition... only issue I am having is to pass image variable and image itself to PHP process page from .js page...

Comment: If you just want to submit you form through an ajax request then just serialize your form : https://jsfiddle.net/y9t00qnk/

Comment: @UgoT. form is not submitted after using serialize because now I am not able to print data on PHP process page. Please let me know.